# Exporting sequences in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I want to export ONLY the sequences created in a Database created in PostgreSQL.
There is any option to do that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 14):

You could write a query to generate a script that will create your existing sequence objects by querying this information schema view.

```
select *
from information_schema.sequences;
```

Something like this.

```
SELECT 'CREATE SEQUENCE ' || sequence_name || ' START ' ||  start_value || ';'
from information_schema.sequences;
```

Comment: When I use select * from information_schema.sequences; I see start value in 1... but the real value showed in pgadmin is 2560061... "CREATE SEQUENCE seq_accidente  INCREMENT 1  MINVALUE 1  MAXVALUE 223372036854775807  START 2560061  CACHE 1;"  
I cant found the real source of the values.
on PG 9.3

Answer (score 5):

I know its too old but today I had similar requirement so I tried to solve it the same way by creating a series of "CREATE SEQUENCE" queries which can be used to RE-create sequences on the other DB with bad import (missing sequences)
here is the SQL I used:

```
SELECT 
'CREATE SEQUENCE '||c.relname||
' START '||(select setval(c.relname::text, nextval(c.relname::text)-1))
AS "CREATE SEQUENCE SQLs"
FROM 
  pg_class c 
WHERE 
  c.relkind = 'S'
```

Maybe that can be helpful for someone.

Comment: I would like to improve a litle bit :

SELECT 
'CREATE SEQUENCE '||c.relname||
' START '||(select setval(c.relname::text, nextval(c.relname::text) - s.seqincrement))
AS "CREATE SEQUENCE SQLs"
FROM 
 pg_class c,
  pg_sequence s
WHERE 
 c.relkind = 'S' and 
 s.seqrelid = c.oid;

Comment: Since sequencers can be in schema's I used this one:
SELECT 
'CREATE SEQUENCE '||c.sequence_schema||'.'||c.sequence_name||
' START '||(select setval(c.sequence_schema||'.'||c.sequence_name, nextval((c.sequence_schema||'.'||c.sequence_name)::regclass)-1))
AS sql_stmt
from information_schema.sequences c

Answer (score 0):

Using DBeaver, you can

1. open a schema
2. select its sequences
3. `crtl-F` to search for the sequences you're interested in
4. `crtl-A` to select all of them
5. `Right-click` and select Generate SQL -> DDL

You will be given SQL statements to create all of the sequences selected.